# youtube-dl through Proxy ( need to escape @ sign)

Tags: windows-7, proxy, cmd.exe, youtube-dl

I am trying to use youtube-dl , using the bellow command, in windows 7.

```
youtube-dl.exe --proxy "http://a12345:A@1@proxy.com:8080/" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzZJuEDQ1a0
```

**username:a12345**

**password:A@1**

**proxy: proxy.com**

The bellow is the response I am getting.

> ```
>   [youtube] Confirming age
>     WARNING: Unable to confirm age: <urlopen error [Errno 10013] An attempt was made
>      to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions>
>     [youtube] XzZJuEDQ1a0: Downloading webpage
>     ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 10013] An attempt was m
>     ade to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions> (caused by
>     URLError(error(10013, 'An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden
>      by its access permissions'),))
> ```

I suspect that its the @ sign in the password, but I cant seem to escape it that it is treated as a normal character.

with verbose

> [debug] System config: [] [debug] User config: [] [debug] Command-line
>
> args: ['--proxy', 'http://a12345:A%401@proxy.com:8080/',
>
> 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bZd5r0iPGc', '--verbose'] [debug]
>
> Encodings: locale cp1252, fs mbcs, out cp437, pref cp1252 [debug]
>
> youtube-dl version 2014.11.27 [debug] Python version 2.7.8 -
>
> Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1 [debug] exe versions: ffmpeg N-68102-, ffprobe
>   N-68102- [debug] Proxy map: {u'http':
>   'http://a12345:A%401@proxy.com:8080/', u'https':
>
> 'http://a12345:A%401@proxy.com:8080/'} [youtube] Confirming age
>
> WARNING: Unable to confirm age:
>
> attempt was made  to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access
>
> permissions> [youtube] 2bZd5r0iPGc: Downloading webpage ERROR: Unable
>
> to download webpage:
>
> to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions>
>
> (caused by URLError(error(10013, 'An attempt was made to access a
>
> socket in a way forbidden  by its access permissions'),))
>
> File "youtube_dl\extractor\common.pyo", line 273, in _request_webpage
>
> File "youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.pyo", line 1321, in urlopen
>   File "urllib2.pyo", line 404, in open >
>   File "urllib2.pyo", line 422, in _open
>   File "urllib2.pyo", line 382, in _call_chain
>   File "youtube_dl\utils.pyo", line 410, in https_open 
>   File "urllib2.pyo", line 1184, in do_open

Comment: nope, does not work.

Comment: Sorry, I just removed the comment to put it as answer. And since it does work for `wget`, I assume it's a bug in youtube-dl

Answer (score 1):

You should encode the `@` character in your password as `%40` in conformance with URI standard:

```
http://a12345:A%401@proxy.com:8080/
```

Since you report this doesn't work in youtube-dl, I suppose the only workaround is to avoid URI special characters in your password. Change your password to include `ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"` if you can.

I'm not sure where the problem is, since urllib2 unquotes the password before passing it to the proxy:

```
    if '@' in host:
        user_pass, host = host.split('@', 1)
        user_pass = base64.encodestring(unquote(user_pass)).strip()
        req.add_header('Proxy-Authorization', 'Basic '+user_pass)
```

and `urllib2.unquote("A%401")` returns `A@1` as expected. Perhaps you should report this to youtube-dl devs.

Comment: sorry mate, it did not work.

Comment: workaround: change your password

Comment: haha, ok will try that, its connected to may other application, part of domain account ..etc.

Comment: I can confirm this system of encoding the @ as %40 in a username does work with my proxy and youtube-dl.  The issue must lie on the server's end.  Now if only I could get https working.

Answer (score -2):

Check if Youtube-dl is blocked by your firewall, if you use an application level firewall. Since it's not digitally signed, some firewalls may block it by default

The error showing up as a file system access issue has to do with the fact that its an app ported from unix, where network access may be represented as files (I assume you've made no changes to your filesystem permisssions)

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157351/why-are-tcp-ip-sockets-considered-open-files

Comment: I had this issue and this fixed it for me

Comment: Because `youtube-dl` is written in Python, what you said about "network access may be represented as files" is most likely incorrect.

Comment: i had this very error today, accidentally blocked the app using  a firewall, restarted my computer several times, i'm using windows 10

Comment: i think it's a linux first app, if you use windows, you can try blocking the app at your firewall and reading the output. YOu can checkk my edit for the link:  from a comment there , Sockets are files. They provide access to streams of bytes through the read/write interface, which is the heart of what it means to be a file